# Inequality in inverse Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, graph-theory, network-flow

I have the following problem, which is motivated by geometric diffusion on a directed graph.

> **Conjecture.** Let $A \in [0,1]^{n\times n}$ be strictly substochastic - i.e. $\forall i ~ \sum_j A_{i,j} < 1$. Define 
> $$B = (I-A)^{-1} = \sum^\infty_{k=0} A^k.$$
> Then
> $$\frac{B_{ii}}{B_{ji}} \geq \frac{B_{ik}}{B_{jk}}, \quad \forall i,j,k.$$

It seems to hold numerically, but I haven't been able to prove it. Is this a known result?